# Getting id from link and using it in javascript

Tags: php, ajax

I have a x number of links on my website like this:

```
<a href="www.link1.com" id="UseLink" value="1">www.link1.com</a>
<a href="www.link2.com" id="UseLink" value="2">www.link2.com</a>
<a href="www.link3.com" id="UseLink" value="3">www.link3.com</a>
```

On the bottom I have a little Javascript that is supposed to do something with the value of the clicked link.

```
    $('#UseLink').click(function(e){ 

    var url = "www.domain.com/uselink"; 

    $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: url,
       data: {'linkid' : this.getAttribute('value')},
       success: function(data)
       {
            console.log("Use link result: " + data);
            if (data === 'success') {
            }
            if (data === 'error') {
            }
       }
    });

    e.preventDefault();

});
```

No matter what link I click, it always uses the id of link1. Anyone knows why this is not working?

Comment: Id's have to be unique. You should use a class here instead.

Answer (score 1):

Id's have to be unique. So do following changes:

```
<a href="www.link1.com" id="1" class="UseLink" value="1">www.link1.com</a>
<a href="www.link2.com" id="2" class="UseLink" value="2">www.link2.com</a>
<a href="www.link3.com" id="3" class="UseLink" value="3">www.link3.com</a>
```

JS:

```
$('.UseLink').click(function(){
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    // id contains the id of clicked anchor
});
```

Comment: That was actually very easy. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

ID must be unique, you have assigned same IDs to all the a tags.
That is why jquery script is hitting the first element.

Answer (score 0):

There probably are plenty of methods to do this with pure javascript but since it has the PHP tag I will give you an answer involving php.

```
<?php
$id = isset($_GET['id']) ? $_GET['id'] : false;
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
var id = '<?= false !== $id ? $id : ""; ?>';
$('#UseLink').click(function(e){ 

  var url = "www.domain.com/uselink"; 

  $.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     url: url,
     data: {'linkid' : id},
     success: function(data)
     {
          console.log("Use link result: " + data);
          if (data === 'success') {
          }
          if (data === 'error') {
          }
     }
  });

  e.preventDefault();

});
</script>
```

The links to trigger this code:

```
<a href="<?= $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>?id=1">Link 1</a>
<a href="<?= $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>?id=2">Link 1</a>
<a href="<?= $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>?id=3">Link 1</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

var value = $( this ).val();
use this above the ajax call and pass the value data

Answer (score 0):

First you need to know the difference between id and class. Id must be unique throughout the page. You can visit this link https://css-tricks.com/the-difference-between-id-and-class/ to learn the id and class.

And according to your problem, if you change id to class, I think it will go good.

Thanks.